# Story of Prophet Yoosuf

Tags: quran, prophets

The story of Prophet Yoosuf is narrated in the Quran. In which part of the Quran is Surah Yoosuf mentioned and write the number of verses in Surah Yoosuf.

Comment: That sounds like homework. Does SE have any policies regarding homework questions? Not to mention that there's little or no research effort.

Answer (score 1):

Well the Story of the Prophet Yusuf (peace be upon him) is mentioned in the Surah ([Yusuf 12](http://www.quran.com/12)) and only a few Verses are not telling his story if you want it more exact between Verse 4 and 101. The Surah itself has 111 Verses.
And this is the only Story of a Prophet which has been revealed at once and stated at once in one Surah (AFAIK).

And Allah knows best!